# google maps api v3 zoom to marker by searchbox

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Firstly I want to apologize for my bad English.
I'm new to google map api and now is developing a map to show markers from mysql data. The plotting markers part is all done by reading this article https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3. 
And now what I'm trying to do is to add a searchbox which will zoom to a certain marker which is already showed on map. I want to know what is the simplest way to do this, a sample code or tutorial will be very useful thing because I'm really is a novice. Thanks in advance! This is my code so far.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>SI-Fas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDOs3oCQK1heWU99CFxtpIAPEqHD0F7X7Q&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var customIcons = {
      PUSKESMAS: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      KLINIK: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      DORUM: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      DORGI: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      RS: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };
    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.789915, 110.374010),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var place = markers[i].getAttribute("place");
          var description = markers[i].getAttribute("description");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + place + "</b> <br/>" + description;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
        var bantulLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://www.bpjskesjogja.com/giskml/bantul11.kml',
            map: map
        });
        var kotaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://www.bpjskesjogja.com/giskml/kota11.kml',
            map: map
        });
        var slemanLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://www.bpjskesjogja.com/giskml/sleman11.kml',
            map: map
        });
        var kulproLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://www.bpjskesjogja.com/giskml/kulpro11.kml',
            map: map
        });
        var gunkidLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://www.bpjskesjogja.com/giskml/gunkid15.kml',
            map: map
        });

    }
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
    function doNothing() {}
    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <!-- <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 630px"></div> -->

  </body>
</html>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1150px; height: 620px">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
        <u style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Legenda:</u><br/><br/>
        <img alt="" src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png" style="height: 16px; width: 12px" />
        PUSKESMAS<br />
        <img alt="" src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png" style="height: 16px; width: 12px" />
        KLINIK<br />
        <img alt="" src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png" style="height: 16px; width: 12px" />
        DOKTER UMUM<br />
        <img alt="" src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png" style="height: 16px; width: 12px" />
        DOKTER GIGI<br />
        <img alt="" src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png" style="height: 16px; width: 12px" />
        RUMAH SAKIT<br />
        <br />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for a marker we would need to keep all the markers in a javascript array. We can set the name property of a marker to the place it corresponds to (provided you want to search the markers by place name). Then for every search text we can loop over this marker array and search the collection for the required marker based on its name.

Once a particular marker is found we can set that marker to the center of the map and optionally zoom the map (as specified by you).

[Check this out](https://jsbin.com/huwovemili/edit?js,output)

Note: Just for you to validate, I have named the places as Place 1, Place 2 etc

Comment: Great example Sir. But as You can see from my code, I'm using data from xml to populate my latlngs. Right now I'm trying to make the search feature using your code as an example. I'm doing it by defining var gmarkers = []; globaly and use gmarkers.push(marker); but the search feature still not functional. Any idea?

Comment: All is good now. many many thanks to you @Bharat Gupta. The error happened because I've yet defined var map globaly

Comment: This was the first solution provided by me on SO... or rather any platform :P. Glad that it was of some purpose to you. Happy to help :)

Comment: Hey @Bharat Gupta can we do same functionality with autocomplete feature?I mean now what u are doing is at first only all places are displayed in dropdown.But what i want is as user types in search box it should fetch all markers from marker array based on matching keywords and then i can select from those suggestions which will show on map?

Comment: @SachinHR sure you can. you can fetch the places as the user types and then you can use the `addMarker` marker function from the sample code to add that place as a marker. Hope it helps!

Comment: I am using angularjs approach.The problem i am facing is I am not able to call setMarkerToCenterA function.ng-click is not working.Can you provide same solution for angularjs?It will be of great help.Everything works but searchHTML += "<li><a href='javascript: setMarkerToCenter(\""+item.name+"\")'>"+item.name+"</a></li>"; is not calling setMarkerToCenter function

Comment: You should not be doing this `searchHTML += "<li><a href='javascript: setMarkerToCenter(\""+item.name+"\")'>"+item.name+"</a></li>";` in angularjs. you should have a `results` model and you should use ng-repeat on it.

Comment: something like: `<li ng-repeat="item in results" ng-click="setMarkerToCenter(item)>{{item.name}}</li>`